# VisualBasic.Net vs Visual C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, reference

Frequently i have to program in VB.Net and Visual C#, so it would be helpful if someone can provide with a list of Refrence for Classes of in VB.net and C#.

I mean like

`My.Computer.Registry` in VB Maps to `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` in C#.

Similarly i want a refrence of other classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you can use the latter in both C# and VB.NET. The former is a VB.NET "crutch" (or "shortcut", to put it nicely) so that VB developers can find stuff via IntelliSense, and are contained within a special assembly used in VB (but that can also needlessly be referenced from C#). My suggestion: don't use "My.*", use the real classes that are available from any .NET language (incl. C#) - it will make moving between languages easier and you will be able to ask BCL questions more clearly on SO.